# Postal MVC3 email headers not being parsed

Tags: email, asp.net-mvc-3

We've used Postal (http://aboutcode.net/postal/) to parse Razor files into email templates before. However using the latest Nuget package (installed today) Postal is refusing to set up the headers in the email message correctly.

This is the test code:

```
var email = new Email("TestEmail");
dynamic message = _emailService.CreateMailMessage(email);
```

(_emailService is set up by AutoFac). The TestEmail.cshtml template contains:

```
To: me@here.com
From: me@here.com
Subject: Test email

This is a test email.
```

On inspection, message.Body is "From: me@here.com\r\nSubject: Test email\r\n\r\nThis is a test email.\r\n" and message.To is empty (Count=0).

There's a _ViewStart.cshtml in the Views/Emails folder to set layout to null and the mail server is correctly set up in web.config. I'm at a loss as to what's going wrong. Can someone offer a suggestion?

Comment: I have a similar problem with MVC4 and there seems to be no solution to this issue.